# Selecting certain features from a dataset according to a list.

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a **dataset "h_train"** which has about 26 features and I have a **list** **H** which has some selected features from the dataset "h_train". I would only like to keep those features in the "h_train" which are present in list H.

```
h_train #Dataset with 26 features [A - Z]
H = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

So I would like h_train to be reduced to only those features in H. How do I do it ?

Comment: `h_train = h_train[H]` assuming `h_train` is a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @Sevanteri Thank you so much! It did work. :)

Comment: dataframes support sub-selection by passing a list of the column labels so Sevanteri's answer is the correct and most succinct answer here

Answer (score 0):

You can transfrom the list into the tuple datastructure and than sue its operators

```
a = tuple(h_train)
b = tuple(H)
c = a & b
only_H_features_left = list(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `h_train` is a `pd.DataFrame` you can just do

```
h_train = h_train[H]
```